# C# Serialize JSON array without using class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, system.text.json

I'm trying to serialize this json structure in c# and was wondering how would I serialize the address array in my structure below without having to use classes

Heres the structure

```
{
    "Name":"Mark",
    "Addresses":[
      {
        "address":"1234 Main street",
      },
      {
        "address":"1234 Pine Street",
      }],
}
```

Here's how I serialize using a JsonSerializer and only serializing one address

```
 string jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
                    {
                        name = "Mark",
                        Addresses = new
                        {
                            address= "1234 Main street"
                        },
                    });
```

How can I serialize the other address

Comment: `Addresses = new []
                        {new {
                            address= "1234 Main street"
                        }, new {.…}},`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate a collection type, such as an array:

```
string jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
{
    name = "Mark",
    Addresses = new[]
    {
        new { address = "1234 Main street" }
    },
});
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HoBJY9)